# How to have a Shell script continue after reboot?

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a Shell script that needs to run in a loop, and perform a series of commands, and when it's finished repeat, hence the loop. Between each command there is a sleep command for a few minutes. The "job" should never terminate. I can have the script start a boot time, but it needs to continue where it left off in the sequence for the commands when the system is rebooted.

How can I best accomplished this? Should I create a MySQL table of the queue of commands, and have it delete each row after each time it successfully executes it? Then when it completes the loops it would re-populate the queue table and start from the top.

It seems like I'm missing something to make this more simple. Thanks in advance for your helpful insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to rewrite your code so that it looks like this:

```
while: ; do
    case $step in
        0) command_1 && ((step++)) ;;
        1) command_2 && ((step++)) ;;
        ...
        9) command_9 && step=0 ;;
        *) echo "ERROR" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

So you would be aware of what has been done by testing the value of `step`.

Then, you may want to set a `trap` before the `while` loop is executed, so that, on exit, the value of `step` is written to a log file:

```
trap "echo step=$step > log_file" EXIT
```

Then, all you need to do is to `source` the log file at the beginning of the script, and the last one will continue its job where it has been stopped.

Comment: Thanks! So it would store the value of step in the log_file, and at the start of the script it would read in this file to get the step value of there it left off? I could also make it so after it does a step++ and also writes this value to the log_file also, just in case it totally gets interrupted like if the UPS failed and it was suddenly without power.

This looks like a good solution!

Comment: @Edward: Indeed, it is a good idea. If you do so, you may want to use something like an "execute" fonction which you would call at each step and which would do all the stuff of incrementation, testing that the command has executed correctly, and writing the value of step to log_file. And don't forget to add the `source log_file` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I'm not clear on what source log_file refers to. Is there a source shell command or is this the variable set to hold the contents of the log_file? Thanks!

Comment: It is a shell command. Basically, what it does is to execute the commands written in the file you `source`. So here it will just assign to the variable `step` the correct value. Try `help source` for informations.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL sounds like a pretty complex solution for this case. In general I would think about some sort of filesystem based markers. You could keep the current state of execution in one or more files e. g. in `/var/run` and make your script check for these files when it starts up.

When you complete one step, you rename the file to reflect the next step that needs to be done and so on.

At the end, rename it or remove it so that the next time the script runs, it will start a new cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a cron job for this. A cron job can run each minute and with a "lock file" strategy you can run the script only if the lock file is not present hence when the previous running script was ended.