# Is it possible to auto reboot for 5 loops through mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am currently using the following command to run reboot

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

however, I would need to run it for 5 loops before and after executing some other programs. Was wondering if it is possible to do it in MINT environment?

Comment: If you reboot the machine the rest of the script won't run. You need to design a way to resume the script after the reboot.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that would be to write the current loop count to a persistent file (not on a tmpfs) like somewhere in `/usr/local/share` so that your can read the current loop count after reboot. (why you want do reboot 5 times is unclear -- this isn't windows - you only need a reboot on kernel update)

Comment: [How to continue a script after it reboots the machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145294/56041), [How to have a Shell script continue after reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14521366/608639), [how to continue a bash script after it reboots the machine from the command after the reboot command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33810686/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to create a file at startup for my reboot script. I incorporated it with the answers provided by swalladge and also shubh. Thank you so much!

```
#!/bin/bash

#testing making a startup application

echo "
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=notify-send success
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_CA]=This is a Test
Name=This is a Test
Comment[en_CA]=
Comment=" > ~/.config/autostart/test.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

First a disclaimer: I haven't tried this because I don't want to reboot my machine right now...

Anyway, the idea is to make a script that can track it's iteration progress to a file as @david-c-rankin suggested. This bash script could look like this (I did test this):

```
#!/bin/sh

ITERATIONS="5"

TRACKING_FILE="/path/to/bootloop.txt"
touch "$TRACKING_FILE"

N=$(cat "$TRACKING_FILE" | wc -c)

if [ "$N" -lt "$ITERATIONS" ]; then
    printf "." >> "$TRACKING_FILE"
    echo "rebooting (iteration $N)"
    # TODO: this is where you put the reboot command
    #       and anything you want to run before rebooting each time
else
    rm "$TRACKING_FILE"
    # TODO: other commands to resume anything required
fi
```

Then add a call to this script somewhere where it will be run on boot. eg. cron (@reboot) or systemd. Don't forget to remove it from a startup/boot command when you're finished or next time you reboot, it will reboot N times.

Not sure exactly how you are planning on using it, but the general workflow would look like:

1. save script to `/path/to/reboot_five_times.sh`
2. add script to run on boot (cron, etc.)
3. do stuff (manually or in a script)
4. call the script
5. computer reboots 5 times
6. anything in the second TODO section of the script is then run
7. go back to step 3, or if finished remove from cron/systemd so it won't reboot when you don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

First create a text document wherever you want,I created one on Desktop,
Then use this file as a physical counter and write a daemon file to run things at startup

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(cat a.txt)
echo "$var"
if [ "$var" != 5 ]
then
    var=$((var+1))
    echo "$var" > a.txt
    echo "restart here"
    sudo shutdown -r now
else
    echo "stop restart"
    echo 0 > a.txt
fi
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I create a `/etc/rc.local` file to execute **user3089519**'s script, and this works for my case. (And for **bootloop.txt**, I put it here: `/usr/local/share/bootloop.txt` )

First: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Then edit this:

```
#!/bin/bash
  #TODO: things you want to execute when system boot.
  /path/to/reboot_five_times.sh 
exit 0
```

Then it works.

Don't forget edit `/etc/rc.local` and remove `/path/to/reboot_five_times.sh` when you done reboot cycling.